# Rodapé do datatable não é exibido

Tags: jsp, jquery-datatables

Seguindo a documentação do datatable: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html, mesmo assim não é exibido nada no rodapé da minha tabela, já chequei meu código umas 20 vezes e não consigo achar onde estou errando. Segue meu jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>BI Lider</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/datatables-responsive/css/dataTables.responsive.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">BI Lider</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Meus Dados</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Configurações</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Sair</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Vendas<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Por Supervisor <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">tabelas</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Acompanhamento por Supervisor</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Aguinaldo 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Código</th>
                                        <th>Nome RCA</th>
                                        <th>Meta</th>
                                        <th>Venda</th>
                                        <th>Perc</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <c:set var="perc" value="${0}" />
                                    <c:forEach var="rca" items="${listaTeste }">
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                            <td>${rca.codusur }</td>
                                            <td>${rca.nome }</td>
                                            <td style="text-align: right"><fmt:formatNumber value="${rca.meta }" pattern="0.00" /></td>
                                            <td style="text-align: right"><fmt:formatNumber value="${rca.venda}" pattern="0.00" /></td>
                                            <td style="text-align: right">${rca.perc1}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" />"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" />" ></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js" />" ></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" />" ></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/bower_components/datatables-plugins/sorting/numeric-comma.js" />" ></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="<c:url value="/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.5/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js" />" ></script>

<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api();

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(3).footer()).html('Teste');

            },
            responsive: true,
            "order": [3, 'desc'],
            "pageLength": 25,
            "language": {
                "info": "Exibindo a página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty":  "Exibindo de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered":   "(filtrados de _MAX_ registros totais)",
                "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "lengthMenu":     "Exibir _MENU_ registros",
                "search":         "Busca:",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":   "Primeira",
                    "last":    "Última",
                    "next":    "Próxima",
                    "previous":"Anterior"
                },
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
                { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
                null,
            ],
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Olhando na documentação a única diferença mesmo é na declaração da variavel api que esta diferente, mas não sei se realmente seja isso. No seu esta `var api = this.api();` e na documentação `var api = this.api(), data;` e isso supondo que esteja rodando o datatable e só o rodapé que não.

Comment: Oi Marcelo, então, incluindo ou não o data no código, não são mostradas as informações no rodapé.

Answer (score -1):

Simplesmente inclua o footer no seu html:

```
<tfoot>
     <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
     </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: exemplo no link:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html